# Can you use FILTER function on top of results from another FILTER function? i.e nesting two FILTER functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel's `FILTER` function takes in the following parameters:

```
=FILTER(array, include, [if_empty])
```

Let's say I use the above function to product a new table, titled `table_2`. Can I then nest table_2 inside another `FILTER` function to produce another output?

I tried the following. Essentially inputting the first output as the array for the nested `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(table_1, a criteria, 0), another criteria, 0)
```

But it seems to give me errors. The reason I am doing this is because my first table has NA's in some columns, and as a result I can't use those columns for my criteria in the `FILTER` function. But I seem to be able to input NOT(ISERROR("column")) as a criteria and it works. But I can chain that with another criteria for whatever reason, hence why I'm looking to nest two `FILTER` functions.

Comment: It can.  Though for us to help you with why, you would need to mock up some data to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: But really all you need to do is to multiply the criteria on the frist FILTER: Ie:   `=FILTER(Array,(1st criteria)*(NOT(ISERROR("column"))))`

Comment: Hi Scott, your formula is what I tried initially which didn't work for me. The reason I suspect that the problem is with the NA cells is because the formula worked up until it got down to a cell that had an NA. I'll create some mock data and see if I can recreate the issue for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say **A1** through **A100** contain 1 through 100.  This:

```
=FILTER(A:A,A:A>50)
```

will give the values from 51 through 100 and this:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A:A,A:A>50),FILTER(A:A,A:A>50)<60)
```

will give the values from 51 through 59:

[image]

but embedding is not required.  This will do the same thing:

```
=FILTER(A:A,(A:A>50)*(A:A<60))
```